# Determining Displacement Field on a Sphere

Tags: boundary-conditions, solid-mechanics

I need to find the displacement field for this sphere shape in terms of $\delta$. So far, by applying boundary conditions, I know $u_r = u_\theta = u_\phi = 0$ at $r = a$ and $u_r = \delta, u_\theta = u_\phi = 0$ at $x = b$.

I am confused on how to go from here, can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework problem? I assume you are trying to use the elasticity equations to obtain an analytical solution? You need to show what you have done so far, prior to applying the boundary conditions.

Comment: Also, this question seems to be more on-topic for Physics.SE than Computational Science.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a Physics question than a Computational Science one.

Due to the symmetry of your problem, you can conclude that the solution is of the form

$$\mathbf{u} = u_r \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r(r)\, ,$$

since the selection of the zenithal and azimuthal angles is arbitrary. This turns the PDE system

\begin{equation}
  (\lambda + \mu) \operatorname{grad} \operatorname{div}\mathbf{u} + \mu \operatorname{rot} \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}\, ,
\end{equation}

into

$$\operatorname{grad}\operatorname{div} \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}\, ,$$

that turns to be an ODE in $r$. After that, you solve your ODE and apply your boundary conditions.